# Create jgw-file

Tags: qgis, autocad, world-file

So, I created a merged geotiff for my area of interest and then used GDAL-transform to get a jpg. This jpg comes with a aux.xml-file storing all georeferencing.

Problem is, AutoCAD demands a jgw-file in order to put the image where it belongs. Any ideas on how to do this? Maybe I missed some option within QGis?

Comment: On option is to create your initial GeoTIFF with option -co TFW=YES and rename then .tfw into .jgw.

Comment: And that's what I forgot, thank you very much. Copy & paste into an answer, if you'd like some more brass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have couple of options:

- Create the initial GeoTIFF with creation option `-co TFW=YES` http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html and rename teh .tfw file into .jgw
- When you convert GeoTIFF into JPEG use creation option `-co WORLDFILE=YES` http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html and rename the .wld file into .jgw.